# Как использовать функцию alert в JavaScript из Java servlet?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, servlet, redirect, alert

Есть сервлет из которого делаю redirect на другой html.

```
case COMPANY:
        CompanyFacade companyFacade = (CompanyFacade) CouponSystem.getInstance().login(username, password, type);
        if(companyFacade != null){
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
            session.setAttribute(COMPANY, companyFacade);
            response.sendRedirect("./html/companySPA_page.html");
        }else{
            //1  response.getWriter().println("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Password is incorrect');</script>");
            //2  response.sendRedirect("./index.html");
        }
        break;
```

В случаи не верного логина пытаюсь вызвать функцию alert с сообщением о не правельном пароле и после чего перенаправить на туже страницу (либо если есть вариант остаться на этой же).
Так вот строка под номером //1 работает если после нее нет редайректа. Вместе эти две строки не работают, не могу понять почему.

Comment: потому что если посылается статус редирект, код не выполняется

Comment: Ну а если первым выполняется строка с Алерт (//1) и потом редайрект (//2)?

Comment: О какой строке речь?

Comment: О первой строке

Comment: Как ты думаешь, что делает эта строка?

Comment: Строка номер 1 вызывает функцию алерт на стороне клиента. Получается что ответ (response)может быть только один, по этому это либо то либо другое. я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68373/discussion-between-grundy-and-tarasula).

Answer (score 2):

И так благодаря помощи Grundy я нашел ответ на свой же вопрос.
Объясню почему это происходит и как можно это решить:

Первая строка генерит код JavaScript и посылает его на сторону клиента на выполнение,
Вторая стока посылает redirect на некий HTML.
Браузер же в свою очередь получив статус redirect не смотрит на тело ответа в котором как раз и записан код JavaScript.

Теперь, одно из решений этой проблемы это сделать redirect на стороне клиента, т.е. с помощью JavaScript, добавив атрибут ***location***

```
response.getWriter().println("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Password is incorrect');location='path/to/page'</script>");
```

Таким образом мы вызываем *alert* в браузере и остаемся на той же странице.